# char() represetation of an array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I had a program that I had to create which took a user inputted odd number between 1 to 99 and created a magic square which I have successfully done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n;

  printf("\nThis programs creates a magic squares of a specified size.\n");
  printf("The size must be an odd number between 1 and 99.\n");
  printf("Enter the size of magic square: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);


  int magicsq[99][99];

  int row = 0;   
  int col = (n - 1) / 2;
  magicsq[row][col] = 1;

  int i;     
  for(i = 2; i <= n * n; i++)
    {
      row = (row + n - 1) % n;

      /*  printf("i = %d\n", i);
      printf("row %d\n", row);

       col = (col % n); */
      col = (col + 1) % n;

      /* printf("col %d\n\n", col); */

      if(magicsq[row][col] != 0)
    { 
      row = (n + row + 2) % n;
      col = (n + col - 1) % n;
      /* printf("n = %d ; row = %d ; col = %d\n", n, row, col); */
    }

      magicsq[row][col] = i;
    }




  printf("\n");
  int j;    
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {                                                     
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {                                                 
      printf("%5d", magicsq[i][j]);                                        
    }                                                                       
      printf("\n");                                                             
    }                                                                           
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

I came across another question which stated me to introduce two functions namely, `void create_magic_square(int n, char magic_square[99][99])` and `void print_magic_square(int n, char magic_square[99][99])`

```
#include <stdio.h>


void create_magic_square(int n, char magic_square[99][99]);
void print_magic_square(int n, char magic_square[99][99]);

int main()
{
  int n;
  char **magic_square;

  printf("\nThis programs creates a magic squares of a specified size.\n");
  printf("The size must be an odd number between 1 and 99.\n");
  printf("Enter the size of magic square: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  create_magic_square(n, magic_square[99][99]);
  print_magic_square(n,  magic_square[99][99]);

  return 0;
}

void create_magic_square(int n, char magic_square[99][99])
{

  int *magicsq[][];
  magic_square[99][99] = magicsq[][];
  int row = 0;   
  int col = (n - 1) / 2;
  magicsq[row][col] = 1;

  int i;     
  for(i = 2; i <= n * n; i++)
    {
      row = (row + n - 1) % n;

      printf("i = %d\n", i);
      printf("row %d\n", row);

      /* col = (col % n); */
      col = (col + 1) % n;

      printf("col %d\n\n", col);

      if(magicsq[row][col] != 0)
    { 
      row = (n + row + 2) % n;
      col = (n + col - 1) % n;
      printf("n = %d ; row = %d ; col = %d\n", n, row, col);
    }

      magicsq[row][col] = i;
    }
}



void print_magic_square(int n, char magic_square[99][99])
{     
  printf("\n");
  int j;    
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {                                                     
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {                                                 
      printf("%5d", magicsq[i][j]);                                        
    }                                                                       
      printf("\n");                                                             
    }
}
```

Upon compiling, I am filled with tons of errors on my declaration of char type array and my usage of the parameters. I have googled char() parameters and types but I am not able to incorporate into my program.

I am new to c so constructive criticism is appreciated and helps me learn better if I am doing anything wrong.

Language: c99 ; Compiler: gcc

Comment: Read errors and warnings. Understand them

Comment: Ps. Get compiler to issue every warning under the sun

Comment: The first thing you need to know is that C does not have parameters of array type. The parameter `magic_square` is really a pointer. This: `magic_square[99][99] = magicsq[][];` is meaningless, to the point that I can't tell what you intended. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). The relationship between arrays and pointers in C can be confusing.

Comment: Additionally, `char **magic_square` declares neither a 2D array of `char`, nor a pointer to one, nor a pointer to an element of one.  That variable is not compatible with the type of your function parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there are lot of mistakes in your code related to pointers and arrays and those can't be completely explained in a single answer here.
I recommend you to study the pointers properly. Relationship between pointers and arrays, Multidimensional arrays are all need to be thoroughly understood before attempting to do what you are trying to.